# Adding 'measures' label to D3 bullet chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with D3's bullet chart and am trying to figure out how to display the actual measures number just to the right of the measures rectangle. Since I want to do this for every bullet chart, I figure it'd be best to do it right in the bullet.js code. I'm rather new to D3 so any help would be much appreciated! [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) is the link to Mike Bostock's bullet chart example with the bullet.js included at the bottom.

It looks like the measures code is handled in this snippet:

```
// Update the measure rects.
            var measure = g.selectAll("rect.measure")
                .data(measurez);

            measure.enter().append("rect")
                .attr("class", function (d, i) { return "measure s" + i; })
                .attr("width", w0)
                .attr("height", height / 3)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
                .attr("y", height / 3)                    
              .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("width", w1)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);  

            measure.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr("width", w1)
                .attr("height", height / 3)
                .attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0)
                .attr("y", height / 3);
```

I thought I could just add something like this after the rect is appended but I've had no such luck.

```
measure.enter().append("text")
.attr("dy", "1em")
.text(function (d) { return d.measurez; })
.attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
.attr("y", height / 3)
.transition()
.duration(duration)
.attr("width", w1)
.attr("x", reverse ? x1 : 0);
```

Thank you in advance for your consideration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it -- there're just two small things to consider. First, you can't call `.enter()` twice. Once the enter selection has been operated on, it's merged into the update selection and your second selection will be empty. This is fixed easily by saving the selection in a variable, but in this case I would recommend making a separate selection for the text labels.

```
var measureLabel = g.selectAll("text.measure")
      .data(measurez);
measureLabel.enter()....;
```

Second, to position the text to the right of the `rect`, you need to take not only the position, but also the width into account when computing the position of the `text` element. Also, you can omit a few elements that are not relevant to `text` elements.

```
measureLabel.enter()
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "measure s" + i; })
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("dx", "1em")
      .text(String)
      .attr("x", reverse ? function(d) { return w0(d) + x0(d); } : w0)
      .attr("y", height / 3);

  measureLabel.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("x", reverse ? function(d) { return w1(d) + x1(d); } : w1);
```

Complete example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/8424257).

Comment: Glad I saw this before I finished writing my answer @LarsKotthoff; nice work!

Comment: This is absolutely perfect! Thank you so much!